# Decorator pattern in C# without Inheritance. Is this correct?

Tags: c#, inheritance, design-patterns, composition

```
 public interface IMovable
    {
        void Move();
    }

    public interface IUnloadable
    {
        void Unload();
    }

    public class Vehicle : IMovable
    {
        public void Move()
        {
            Console.Write("moving");
        }
    }

    public class Truck : IMovable, IUnloadable
    {
        private Vehicle Veh;

        public Truck(Vehicle veh)
        {
            this.Veh = veh;
        }

        public void Move()
        {
            Veh.Move();
            Console.Write("reverse with beepy noise as well");
        }

        public void Unload()
        {
           Console.Write("Unload");
        }
    }
```

If this is the decorator pattern. What is the difference between the decorator pattern and composition? I have seen examples of this pattern where inheritance is used. For instance the Java example on Wikipedia.

I don't see the need to use inheritance at all, or am I missing something?

Comment: `What is the difference between the decorator pattern and composition?` Conceptually, a decorator modifies the behavior of the (single) object it wraps, whereas the composite (pattern) has behavior based on the combination of the (multiple) objects it aggregates.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Decorator pattern by definition will implement the same interface as the component it is decorating. Idea is that the client code doesn't needs to change. It can rely on the same abstraction it was using earlier.

For example:

```
public interface IMovable
{
    void Move();
}

public class Truck : IMovable
{
    public void Move()
    {
        Console.Write("moving");
    }
}

public class NoisyMovable : IMovable //1.Implement same interface
{
    private IMovable movable;
    public NoisyMovable(IMovable movable)//2.Wrap same interface
    {
        this.movable = movable;
    }

    public void Move()
    {
        movable.Move();            
        Console.Write("Make noise");
    }
}
```

If you note the `NoisyMovable` class, it is a decorator because it implements the `IMovable` abstraction and wraps the same.

With that, you don't have to create many classes like `NoisyVehicle`, `NoisyTruck`, `NoisyCar` etc. Just the `Car`, `Truck` are enough; you can add the noise by using the single decorator.

```
IMovable movable = new NoisyMovable(new Truck ());//Noisy Truck
IMovable movable = new NoisyMovable(new Car());//Noisy car
//etc
```

Composition on the other hand doesn't need to wrap the same implementation of the interface it implements. It can implement one interface and wrap any other.

What you have got wrong is your `Truck` class takes the instance of `Vehicle`. It shouldn't, instead it should take any instance of `IMovable`. It should work with any implementation of `IMovable`.

Comment: So if I wanted to have the NoisyMovable class to be IUnloadable as well I would implement IUnloadable and inject IUnloadable into its constructor? So two params? Or would i rather create a new class that decorates NoisyMovable? But then i wouldn't inject an interface but a concrete class...

Comment: @user1809104 You could implement `IUnloadable` in `NoisyMovable` but that's not useful. Because you can store it as either `IUnloadable` or `IMovable` if you follow loose coupling. If you need to decorate `IUnloadable`, you either need to wrap another `IUnloadable` or you need a unified interface which is `IUnloadable` and also `IMovable`

Answer (score 1):

> What is the difference between the decorator pattern and composition?

Conceptually, a decorator modifies the behavior of the (single) object it wraps, whereas the composite (pattern) has behavior based on the combination of the (multiple) objects it aggregates.

> I dont see the need to use inheritance at all, or am I missing something?

Inheritance is useful so that you can have multiple decorators, and nest them. For example, a `SelfDriver` that wraps a `Truck` that wraps a `Vehicle`. Ignoring `IUnloadable`, the second decorator would be 
`SelfDriver`:

[image: Class diagram in PlantUML]

The code would look like this:

```
IMovable sd = new SelfDriver(new Truck(new Vehicle())));
```

The object diagram would look like this:

[image: Object diagram in PlantUML]